# Making a docker container available outside my VM on the same network?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtualbox, host, docker-container

After installing iPeer, https://github.com/ubc/iPeer/, it worked brilliantly on my VM locally. Now I am trying to figure out how to make the website iPeer available outside of my VM

How can I make it available, iPeer, outside of my VM on the same network? For example, another computer on the same network?

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

For exposing container to the rest of the network you need to map a port of the VM to a port of the container. Looking through the README of iPeer there a few examples, please copy the line you are using to run the container.

Looks like there a few options to run iPeer:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -e SE_OPTS="-enablePassThrough false" -e TZ="Canada/Pacific" --name selenium-local --shm-size 2g selenium/standalone-firefox:3.7.1-argon
```

On docker running with `-p HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT` let's you map a port to be accesible from the network as if it were running directly on the VM. (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose)

For docker-compose option there's a similar way of configuring it, for instance:
(https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose)

```
version: "3.8"

version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    container_name: ipeer_db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=randompassword
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=ipeer
      - MYSQL_USER=ipeer
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=ipeer
    volumes:
      - ./.data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "13306:3306"
```

Maps the local por 13306 to the container port 3306 and allows you to access it from outside.

If you are using the default docker-compose from that repository it looks its exposing:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    ports:
      - "13306:3306"
  app: &app
    ports:
      - NOT_SPECIFED
  worker: &worker
    ports:
      - "9002:9000"
  web:
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
  app-unittest:
    ports:
      - "9001:9000"
  web-unittest:
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
```

Maybe the app is the one that's not being exposed?